# Drawing link with d3 and d3-flextree plugin

Tags: d3.js

I'm (still) trying to make an orgchart with D3 and d3-flextree plugin. I struggle drawing the links between the nodes. The "equation" I use consider the middle of the node (as I understand it) whereas I'd like to draw from the end of a node.
I think my mistake is in my drawing-link function

```
function diagonal(s, d) {
  path = `M ${s.x} ${s.y}
  L ${s.x} ${(s.y + d.y) * 0.5},
  ${d.x} ${(s.y + d.y) *  0.5 },
  ${d.x} ${d.y}`
  return path
}
```

It's hard to explain so I made a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ymv5sr9k/11/ 
In this exemple all links are the way I want thanks to right padding, but as soon as the nodeSize change (see the big node) it's all broken. I guess I need a more general drawing-link function but I can't figure it out

Thanks for reading,
Zoom

Comment: where is the mid bottom relative to the box center?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand the question, when I said center it's because I multiply by 0.5 in the path equation. Is it what you talk about ?

Comment: you calculate the mid point between the centers of the nodes, I talk about the node box

Comment: I think I understood something ^^ What I do : I draw from nodeParent to nodeChild. this result in : topParentBox to topChildBox. So I know that I rather want => bottomParentBox to topChildBox. It's probably something like : (nodeParent + nodeSize) to nodeChild. But I dont successfully acces to nodeSize AND all my attempts to change the equation resulted in non-sense. I hope it's not to confuse... Thank you for your time, I'm really grateful !

Comment: if you need some data in some objects put it in so you can use it in the link calculation

Comment: I progress ! The solution is not to move start point, but move the emplacement of the horizontal line adding nodeSize - padding to the y coordinate of the two "control point". It worked doing it manually, so I just need to find a way to access nodeSize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! As i said in the comments, I needed to move the horizontal line. I added `nodeSize` in my two `y` "control points". And nodeSize is actually `source.y - destination.y - padding`. This is my final equation:

```
function diagonal(s, d) {
    var nodeSize = s.y - d.y - 30
    return "M" + s.x + "," + s.y
        + "L" + s.x + "," + (d.y + s.y + nodeSize) / 2
        + " " + d.x + "," +  (d.y + s.y + nodeSize) / 2
        + " " + d.x + "," + d.y;
};
```

Thank you for your time!